# Does Ajax always require the use of node.js?

Tags: ajax

I learning about the use of AJAX in web development, and I need to know if AJAX always require the use of node.js, or JQUERY?

Thanks.

Comment: Ajax only requires Javascript. Node.js is a server side technology and jQuery is a Javascript framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very broad question, so the answer might be broad as well:

The short answer: Ajax does not require jQuery nor Node.js.

In practice, Ajax is a technology for asynchronous operations utilized by Javascript send data to and retrieve from a server asynchronously(1). Ajax is fully available in plain, vanilla Javascript, and it works as follows (example taken from Wikipedia, see sources):

```
// This is the client-side script.
// Initialize the Http request.
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', 'send-ajax-data.php');
// Track the state changes of the request.
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
    if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === OK) {
            alert(xhr.responseText); // 'This is the returned text.'
        } else {
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
        }
    }
};
// Send the request to send-ajax-data.php
xhr.send(null);
```

This is a classic example, showing both how to use Ajax with vanilla Javascript, and also why it's much easier with other means such as jQuery, shortening the same snippet to just:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
}).done(function(data) {
    // Do something with data.
});
```

*Sources (including vanilla Ajax examples):*

- 1. [Wikipedia: Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))
- 2. [A Guide to Vanilla Ajax Without jQuery](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-vanilla-ajax-without-jquery/)
- 3. [jQuery: ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use node.js to perform an Ajax request. You can make an Ajax request even using vanilla Javascript. However, jQuery made the `Ajax` request is very easy and cross-browser compatible with just some lines of code. So, I recommend you to stick with jQuery instead of using vanilla Javascript.

You can find more information regarding the jQuery Ajax feature here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You can also find more information about the vanilla Javascript Ajax request feature here:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

No, most browsers supply means to perform asynchronous javascript requests but libraries such as jQuery partly came about to smooth over the differences between browsers, making ajax a lot more portable.

Modern browsers generally don't have so great differences, so portability is probably is less of an issue, but using libraries has become common practice.